# Upload Django static files to Amazon S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I am trying to find a way to upload my Django static files to an Amazon S3 bucket.

In my `settings.py` I have:

```
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'XXXXX'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AXXXXXA'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'DXXXXXXXXX6'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
```

I upload my Django code to an AWS EB instance as a zip file using the EB control panel upload feature.

What is the recommended way to make sure my static files (in the static/ directory) get copied to the S3 bucket?

Comment: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2014/11/10/Using-Amazon-S3-to-store-your-Django-sites-static-and-media-files/

Comment: Yes I have tried collectstatic but that does not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would try doing a setup like this:

**settings.py:**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join('path', 'to_your', 'files'),
)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AXXXXXA'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'DXXXXXXXXX6'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'XXXXX'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'proj.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'  # static files
STATIC_S3_PATH = 'media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'proj.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'  # media uploads
DEFAULT_S3_PATH = 'static/'
S3_URL = '//{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_S3_PATH
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + DEFAULT_S3_PATH
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/domain.com/proj/static/media'  # assuming this is your layout
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/domain.com/proj/static/static'  # assuming this is your layout
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_S3_SECURE_URLS = True
date_three_months_later = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(3 * 365 / 12)
expires = date_three_months_later.strftime('%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 EST')
AWS_HEADERS = {
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=31536000',  # 365 days
}
```

**s3utils.py:**
*make sure you install `django-storages` and `boto`*

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

That should make sure everything goes to your S3 bucket.